# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement **tusclient**

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, tus

Iam getting  the following error while trying to do "***pip install tusclient***".

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement **tusclient** . Error: No matching distribution found for tusclient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [This](https://github.com/tus/tus-py-client). This will solve you problem.
https://github.com/tus/tus-py-client

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `tusclient` is only available for `python2` not for `python3` according to [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/tusclient/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`tuspy`](https://pypi.org/project/tuspy/):

```
pip install tuspy
```

.